# Emtpy a Cell If another Cell becomes empty

Tags: excel, vba

Good day dear community,

I currently have a problem with VBA/Excel that I can't find a solution to. What I want to achieve is not complicated, but I can't find a way.

Let's assume we have two columns. In any row of one column A the User enter a value and then I start a macro. This macro executes certain instructions. Among other things, this macro ensures that if a cell in column A has a value, then the value "Yes" is entered in the same row in column B. Now my problem: As soon as the user deletes the cell value in column A, the value "Yes" in column B should also be deleted. At first glance you might think that i can use this confdition:

```
=IF(A1="";"";yes)
```

The problem is that as soon as the user has entered a value in the cell, "yes" is immediately written in the cell, but this is not desired. Because this task should be taken over by the macro.

As a small side note: I have simplified my problem. Due to the structure of my project, only the macro is allowed to write "yes".

Thanks.

Comment: `If Cells(i, 1) = vbnullstring Then Cells(i, 2) = vbnullstring`

Comment: This is handled with a simple formula in `B1`: `=IF(A1<>"","Yes","")`. Can we see your code so far, so we can understand why you would need VBA for it and/or do some clarifications? Any of it is doable.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I also tried the formular and this works finde. But i dont want that the formular writes the "yes". This is the job of my macro. I can't expain you why this is so, it would be complicated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Evaluate Excel Formula in VBA

- In your code, you will define the occupied range in column A, and apply the second line appropriately.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub checkColumnRange()

    ' Some code

    ' Define the column range...
    ' e.g.:
    Dim rg As Range: Set rg = Range("A1:A10")
    rg.Offset(, 1).Value = Evaluate("IF(" & rg.Address(0, 0) _
        & "<>"""",""Yes"","""")")

    ' Some code

End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you. To solve this problem with vba was not my first priority. But if theres no solution to solve this provlem without vba, then i will do it like your code. Thanks.